# nodemon crashed waiting for file changes before starting

Tags: reactjs, npm, web, youtube, nodemon

I make website social media like Facebook with language react.js, when I write NPM start give me  this problem : NODEMON app crashed -waiting for file changes before starting ,how to solve the problem .I do same thing video teaching on YOUTUBE in video write listening at 5000 but me give me this problem. He work with website MONGODB TO CREATE USER,POST AND OTHER
also before this thing give code: MODULE_NOT_FOUND
but in folder project you have node_modules
I want to solve the problem to add user to make page login sign up

Comment: Can you share your packages.json?

Comment: also code samples

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.